# can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str? How to get rid of tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I have this project for uni and I am sure my question is dumb, but I am no programmer and I really can't fix it, even though I read most questions on this topic. 
This is my code:

```
        sql_cmd = "SELECT Offer.FirstName, Offer.PhoneNumber, Offer.PostCode, Offer.Product FROM Offer "
        Offer_from_db = executeSQLCommand (sql_cmd)
        Offer_table_html_string = ""

        for offer_record in Offer_from_db:
            Product = offer_record [0]
            Name = offer_record [1]
            PhoneNumber = offer_record [2]
            PostCode = offer_record [3]


            Offer_table_html_string += "<tr>" + "<td>" + str (Product) + "</td>","<td>"+ str(Name) +"</td>" ,"<td>"+  str (PhoneNumber) +" </td>", "<td>"+ str (PostCode) +" </td>"
```

My error log says

```
Error running WSGI application
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str
File "/var/www/davidds_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 505, in application
Offer_table_html_string += "<tr>" + "<td>" +  str (Product) + "</td>","<td>"+  str (Name) +"</td>" ,"<td>"+  str (PhoneNumber) +" </td>", "<td>"+  str (PostCode) +" </td>"
```

I also tried:
`Product = str (offer_record [0]) but it didn't work. Please help!`

Comment: `"</td>" ,"<td>"` in the middle of your line is a tuple (note that the comma makes the tuple, you don't need parentheses to get one). You want `+` instead of `,`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want to add several elements to your `Offer_table_html_string`, right?  So, if I understand your intentions right, then what you want to do is basically the following:

```py
Offer_table_html_string += "<tr>" + "<td>" + str(Product) + "</td>"
Offer_table_html_string += "<td>" + str(Name) + "</td>"
Offer_table_html_string += "<td>" + str(PhoneNumber) + " </td>"
Offer_table_html_string += "<td>" + str(PostCode) + " </td>"
```

Now, you can certainly do that in one go, but then you have to concatenate the individual parts of your html string using `+` again, not a comma, i.e.

```py
Offer_table_html_string += ("<tr>" + 
    "<td>" + str(Product) + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + str(Name) + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + str(PhoneNumber) + " </td>" +
    "<td>" + str(PostCode) + " </td>"
)
```

Note how I put the entire string into parentheses, so that I can split it to several lines, without having to worry about newlines.

If you use commata to separate the individual parts of your table, your actually creating a tuple.  Hence:

```py
Offer_table_html_string += ("<tr>" + 
    "<td>" + str(Product) + "</td>",
    "<td>" + str(Name) + "</td>",
    "<td>" + str(PhoneNumber) + " </td>",
    "<td>" + str(PostCode) + " </td>"
)
```

is the same as:

```py
Offer_table_html_string += ("<tr><td>some_product</td>", "<td>some_name</td>",
                            "<td>55512345</td>", "<td>56789</td>")
```

And this does not work because on the right you now have a tuple, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```py
Offer_table_html_string += f"<tr><td>{str(Product)}</td><td>{str(Name)}</td><td>{str(PhoneNumber)}</td><td>{str(PostCode)}</td>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Offer_table_html_string += "<tr>" + "<td>" + str (Product) + "</td>","<td>"+ str(Name) +"</td>" ,"<td>"+  str (PhoneNumber) +" </td>", "<td>"+ str (PostCode) +" </td>"
```

The program thinks you are creating a tuple because you have commas in your expression outside of any strings.

I'm assuming you want a single HTML string like `"<tr> <td> ... </td> <td> ... </td> </tr>"`, so you should just replace all commas with a + in that entire line.

Or, you can do the following:

```
Offer_table_html_string += "<tr><td>" + str(Product) + "</td><td>" + str(Name) + "</td><td>" + str(PhoneNumber) + "</td><td>" + str(PostCode) + "</td>"
```

This should suit your needs

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is arising from the comma (,) present between the `"</td>"` and `"<td>"`. If you want the comma inside the string then it should be within the quotes, it's currently outside of it. Looking at the code in any editor with syntax highlighting or even here on StackOverflow in your question should make that clear to you. Just put the commas inside the quotes or remove them entirely.

Without commas at all:

```
Offer_table_html_string += "<tr>" + "<td>" + str (Product) + "</td><td>"+ str(Name) +"</td><td>"+  str (PhoneNumber) +" </td><td>"+ str (PostCode) +" </td>"
```

With commas in quotes:

```
Offer_table_html_string += "<tr>" + "<td>" + str (Product) + "</td>,<td>"+ str(Name) +"</td>,<td>"+  str (PhoneNumber) +" </td>,<td>"+ str (PostCode) +" </td>"
```

Both of these ought to work. Choose whichever you actually meant to do.